# Associative container with queue-like properties on the values

Tags: c++, dictionary, priority-queue

I have data in the form of instances of a POD struct. Under "normal" conditions, I need to access them via a unique ID, currently via a `std::map`. If something goes wrong, however, I need to traverse the data in an order provided by a specific member of the POD struct.

I don't want to copy all data sets of the map to a priority queue in case of error -- this seems much to expensive.

I tried running `std::make_heap` on the `std::map`, but that doesn't even compile, because the `map`'s iterators cannot be subtracted.

The sort keys will change on a regular basis, so keeping the data in a priority queue and just storing pointers in the map seems not to be feasible, especially as access via the map (the typical use-case) becomes more expensive by the indirection.

The other way around, i.e. storing pointers in a separate data structure that can be heapified on demand seems feasible, but the synchronization might be error-prone.

Is there anything in the `std` libraries, boost or tbb that would accomplish what I want?

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but did you check the [boost::multi-index library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)?

Comment: @rodrigo Apart from some funny business with `const`, this would be it. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a work for the [Boost Multi-Index Containters Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).